# Why use 'ln -sf' in Linux?

Tags: shell, ln

I have 2 questions. The first one is for the `-sf` options and the second one is for the more specific usage of `-f` options.

By googling, I figured out the description of command `ln`, option `-s` and `-f`.

(copy from http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ln.htm)

```
-s, --symbolic : make symbolic links instead of hard links
-f, --force : remove existing destination files
```

I understand these options individually. But, how could one use this `-s` and `-f` options simultaneously? `-s` is used for creating a link file and `-f` is used for removing a link file. Why use this merged option?

To know more about `ln` command, I made some examples.

```
$ touch foo     # create sample file
$ ln -s foo bar # make link to file
$ vim bar       # check how link file works: foo file opened
$ ln -f bar     # remove link file
```

Everything works fine before next command

```
$ ln -s foo foobar
$ ln -f foo     # remove original file
```

By the description of `-f` option, this last command should not work, but it does! `foo` is removed.

Why is this happening?

Comment: `-f` stands for **force** (`--force`); not for remove!

Comment: To add a reason to terdon's answer...  One of the usage is when manually updating libraries.  If you do it in two steps - first rm to remove the old link, then ln -s to create a new one - the library won't work between the operations... which becomes a great problem if the ln command needs the library to work.  So with ln -sf , the old link is replaced with a new, without the link ever being broken.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First of all, to find what a command's options do, you can use `man command`. So, if you run `man ln`, you will see:

```
   -f, --force
          remove existing destination files

   -s, --symbolic
          make symbolic links instead of hard links
```

Now, the `-s`, as you said, is to make the link symbolic as opposed to hard. The `-f`, however, is not to remove the link. It is to overwrite the destination file if one exists. To illustrate:

```
 $ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Mar 26 13:18 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Mar 26 13:18 foo

$ ln -s foo bar  ## fails because the target exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘bar’: File exists

$ ln -sf foo bar   ## Works because bar is removed and replaced with the link
$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 3 Mar 26 13:19 bar -> foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Mar 26 13:18 foo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
By default, each destination (name of new link) should not already exist.
  [...]   

--backup[=CONTROL]
              make a backup of each existing destination file
  [...]

 -f, --force
              remove existing destination files
```

You have to read carefully to understand what is meant in `man ln`. "Remove" is a bit misleading without the context.

With `-i` you get the question:

**`ln: replace 'q2'? y`**

Remove, overwrite, replace...

---

POSIX (`man 1p ln`) has:

```
-f
    Force existing destination pathnames to be removed to allow the link.
```

This is a very good addition "...to allow the link".

---

And `info ln` has:

> Normally 'ln' does not replace existing files.  Use the '--force'
>   ('-f') option to **replace** them unconditionally, the '--interactive'
>   ('-i') option to replace them conditionally, and the '--backup' ('-b')
>   option to **rename** them.

"--backup" example: with a existing `qli -> qqq`:

`ln -sb ttt qli`

```
09:10 qli -> ttt
08:47 qli~ -> qqq
```